# Java null pointer exception after checking if null

Tags: java

Can anybody explain how is it possible that I am getting null pointer exception thrown from this line of code:

```
if (data != null && data.isActive()) {
```

Body of method isActive() is just:

```
public Boolean isActive() 
{
  return active;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it possible that the `NPE` is thrown within or by `method()`?

Comment: Edit your question and add method() source

Comment: Maybe data exists but has no method named "method"?

Comment: What are inside the `data.method()`?

Comment: data may not be null, but `method()` might be throwing a NPE. post the method() code.

Comment: Are you sure that `NPE` is not thrown from within the `method() `?

Comment: It is possible that `data` is not null but `.method()` is failing. Your stack trace would prove this. Please supply more code or your full stacktrace.

Comment: What is the `active` in your method body?

Comment: Does your `isActive` method returns `boolean` and `active` is `Boolean` (wrapper)?

Comment: The more information you supply the more likely we'll be able to help. Stacktrace please

Comment: Your edit didnt help too much. Now we need all assignments to active variable

Comment: your `active` variable is null, and java gets NPE when tries to unbox null value

Comment: It seems like Boolean object isnt initializaed

Comment: please post a SCCE (self contained, compilable example).  that will help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In java, there's a thing called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), when primitive values are wrapped by object types and vice versa.

So, in your code there is a method:

```
public Boolean isActive() 
{
  return active;
}
```

note, that you are returning `Boolean` (object type), not `boolean` (primitive type).

and return value is going to be used in your if statement.

```
if (data != null && data.isActive()) {
```

when java meets `data.isActive()` in your `if` statement, it tries to convert Boolean value to primitive boolean value, to apply it for your logical operation.

But your `active` variable inside of your `isActive()` method is null, so java is unable to unbox this variable to `boolean` primitive value, and you get `Null pointer exception`.

Comment: whoever downvote my answer, please leave a comment, to let me know, what is wrong with my assumptions. Thank you.