# NullPointerException throws when I use ternary operator

Tags: java, boolean, ternary-operator, boxing, unboxing

I have the following return statement:

```
public Boolean foo(String booleanString){  
    return ("true".equals(booleanString) ? true : ("false".equals(booleanString) ? false : null));
}
```

when `booleanString` equal not `true` and not `false` I get the `NullPointerException`.

Is it boxing/unboxing issue?

Comment: what value is there in booleanString

Comment: Yes. It is trying to convert `null` to Boolean i guess. Could you post method signature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You guessed it right. For a formal explanation, the answer lies in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and
>   the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion
>   (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

So as you have the primitive `true` and `false` in both expressions, the type of your condition expression is `boolean`.

When you get into the second expression, in the second case, the null reference is converted into boolean with `null.booleanValue();`, causing the NPE, so that the expression is equivalent to:

```
return Boolean.valueOf(null.booleanValue());
```

(then the return type of the expression is re-boxed to `Boolean`, but it's too late as you guessed it).

For example:

```
return ("true".equals(booleanString) ? Boolean.TRUE : ("false".equals(booleanString) ? Boolean.FALSE : null));
```

does not cause a NPE since the type of the expression is `Boolean`. This, however,

```
return ("true".equals(booleanString) ? true : ("false".equals(booleanString) ? Boolean.FALSE : null));
```

causes it because again the same rule applies (since the first expression is the primitive `boolean` type). So it's equivalent to:

```
return Boolean.valueOf(("true".equals(booleanString) ? true : ("false".equals(booleanString) ? Boolean.FALSE : null).booleanValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning object type `Boolean`, then java tries to unbox return value `null` to a `boolean` primitive type in a logical expression, where `foo()` has been using. And you get Null Pointer Exception.

Here is a similar case and my explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30055584/784540